# OLEDB insert rows into a replaced table

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I'm trying to replace the table in Excel 2007 using OLEDB.

Firstly I'm executing the command "Drop Table", than "Create Table" and it works fine.

But if I now want to insert data `("INSERT INTO")` into this table, it fails. There are no errors or exceptions by `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, transaction commits at the end succesffuly, the database is just empty.

Any ideas why?

```
connection.Open();
string access_com = "DROP TABLE " + globalPrefix + prefix + TableName;
OleDbCommand execute = new OleDbCommand(access_com, connection);
try
{
  execute.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ConfigDataSet.Log.AddLogRow("The program cannot drop table you want. Close the file with it and run program again!", 1);
  return 1;
}
access_com = "CREATE TABLE [" + globalPrefix + prefix + TableName + "]" + fieldString + ")";// CONSTRAINT PK" + TableName + " PRIMARY KEY " + primaryKey + ")";
execute.CommandText = access_com;
execute.ExecuteNonQuery();

OleDbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
access_com = "INSERT INTO " + TableName + "( " + allfields + ")" + " VALUES (" + parametersString + ")";
OleDbCommand execute = new OleDbCommand(access_com, connection);
execute.Transaction = transaction;
try
{
  execute.ExecuteNonQuery();
  execute.Parameters.Clear();
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
  ConfigDataSet.Log.AddLogRow("Inserting row failed: ", 2);
  failedInsertions++;
}
```

Comment: could u post a lil bit more code.. to have a look at it..

Comment: What kind of Table (sheet or range?), can you verify that the DROp works?

Comment: A sheet. I'm quite sure, because the table I want to replace is full of records, and after executing the code it's empty

Comment: The same code works on MSAccess and SQL server fine

Answer (score 0):

You have the INSERT query in a transaction, but I don't see a commit anywhere in your code:

```
execute.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction.Commit();
```

You should probably also have the `transaction.Rollback();` in your exception block.  See [OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93ehy0z8.aspx)

Comment: This transaction is committed later, after inserting group of rows. This is not the reason. I guess there is something wrong with "DROP TABLE ", I found information that it cannot work correctly in Excel